# RFC4646 と UNIX 環境変数の違い

Tags: unix

UNIX 環境変数 `LC_***` 系に設定する値は [RFC3066](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3066.txt) というか [RFC4646](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4646.txt) にほぼ基づいているようですが、微妙に差異があるようです。
- 区切りコード: RFC4646 では `%x2D` (ハイフン-マイナス) に対し、環境変数では `%x5F` アンダースコア
- RFC4646 には case insensitive とあるが、環境変数では使い分けがされているようだ

そして実際、下記のようなコマンドを入力してもエラーは出ず結果は同じでした。
(cygwin と hpux-11.11 でチェック)

```
$ LC_ALL=ja_JP.utf8 sort hoge.txt > piyo1.txt
$ LC_ALL=ja-JP.utf8 sort hoge.txt > piyo2.txt
$ LC_ALL=JA-JP.UTF8 sort hoge.txt > piyo3.txt
$ LC_ALL=ja-jp.utf8 sort hoge.txt > piyo4.txt
```

Q1. この微妙な差の由来をご存知だったら教えてください。
Q2. 環境変数に使う最適記法を教えてください。
Q3. URI に使う場合の最適記法を教えてください。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

部分回答ですが…

`LC_*`および`LANG`が取る値の共通形式はPOSIX([IEEE Std 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_02))で定義されていて、次のとおりです (@modifierは`LANG`以外)。他の形式は実装依存です。

*language*[_*territory*][.*codeset*][@*modifier*]

*language*と*territory*は慣習的にはそれぞれ[ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)と[ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)が使われてますし、個別の実装のマニュアルでも大抵そう記してあるんですが([例](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setlocale.3.html))、POSIXドキュメント内での明確な言及は見つけられませんでした。RFCの方は明確な言及がありますね。

なお、RFC4646はobsoletedで、最新は[RFC5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646)じゃないかな。

- Q1: 歴史的になぜ差が生じたかはわかりません。規格的には、Unixの環境変数は準拠する規格が違うから、ということになります。アンダースコアのかわりにハイフンでも良し、とするのは実装の拡張だと思います。
- Q2: 環境変数に使う場合はPOSIXどおり、アンダースコアを使うのが無難だと思います。大文字小文字についてはPOSIX内に定義がなく、ISOでは*language*を小文字、*territory*を大文字、が推奨されていますが、POSIX内の例では*language*の最初を大文字にしているんですよね。
- Q3: URIに使う、というのは特定のschemeで定義されてるのでない限りは作成者の自由でしょう。ただ、多くの場面でlanguage tagとして使う場合はRFCの形式の方を使うでしょうから、RFCに合わせておくのが無難じゃないかなと思います。

Comment: 根拠となる規格が違う、および、多くの処理系では拡張機能を実装している、ということで納得です。